# Trying to find birth certificate or any birth records for Heinz Gunther Curdt (German ancestry)

Tags: germany, birth-records

I have been extensively researching my family ancestry. My grandfather is German and moved to England at age 7 around 1950-1952.

I am trying to find out anything about my great grandfather, Heinz Gunther Eduard Curdt.

On Ancestry there is only one record where he lived (Hameln 1950).
Heinz married my grandfathers mum ( Ursula Katherine Marx) who is now deceased.

I also know that he was alive 1959 -1960 because of the housing record so he did not die before then.

I am trying to find Heinz records maybe his birth certificate or anything useful. I have searched ancestry but not sure of any other websites specifically for german ancestry

Comment: Please be aware of our Privacy Policy that applies to mentioning the name or other identifying information of anyone born more than 100 years ago.  It's not always forbidden but to understand the exceptions see our [help/on-topic].

Comment: Where did you post before?  If it was here then please provide a link to your earlier question.

Comment: If your grandfather was born around 1943-1945, that means your great-grandfather was of an appropriate age to have served in the German army in WWII. Have you looked for military records?

Comment: I have checked all ancestry records and only found two records showing he lived in Hameln. I have looked through ancestry military records Among other websites but found nothing @lejonet

Comment: Also I only know he’s my granfathers dad because of my granfathers birth certificate (paper copy) but don’t know anything else except he married my grandfathers mum at some point since her last name was curry on her death certificate and not Marx

Comment: @lejonet The one that was a toddler was the **grandfather** and I said the **great-grandfather** would have been of an age to go to war.

Comment: My grandfather is early 70s and born in Hameln

Comment: I have edited your question title and the tags to narrow your question to records which might have infomration about a birth record or record containing information about his birth. Broad questions which ask for any infrmation are not a good fit for this site.  Your question could be improved by making it clearer what records you already have on hand and which records you've searched for unsuccessfully. You can use the edit button beneath your question to add information.  The [help] has more information on how the site works.

Answer (score 2):

If he was 7 in 1950, then due to data protection laws, the data may not be publicly available yet. If the chances are good that he was actually born in Hameln, try contacting the Standesamt in Hameln. There are online forms to request documents (of yourself or of ancestors):

https://www.hameln.de/de/buergerservice-verwaltung/buergeranliegen/online-formulare/

Answer (score 1):

Church records for Hameln are available on [Archion](https://www.archion.de/en/) for Lutheran churches and on [Matricula Online](https://data.matricula-online.eu/en/deutschland/hildesheim/hameln-st-augustinus/) for the Roman-Catholic church. Don't expect an index for it. There is also an entry at [GenWiki about Hameln](http://genwiki.genealogy.net/Hameln) (German) where you might find other resources or links to e.g. Genealogical Societies that could be of further help. I had a casual look at the linked cemetery index (look for "Grabsteine"), the family database (first two entries below "Genealogische Quellen") and the Address Book of 1929 (look for "Addressbücher für Hameln") but I was not very successful for "Curdt". You should watch out for the possibility that the name was slightly altered in England and is spelled slightly differently in the German variant.